# "Required permission was denied!" when requesting WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission on Android 10. I do that using the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
}
if (this.checkSelfPermission(ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
}
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q &&
        this.checkSelfPermission(ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
}
if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    permissions.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}
if (permissions.size() > 0) requestPermissions(permissions.toArray(new String[0]), PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
```

Here is the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

All other permissions work except WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. When I try to request it, it does not display any dialog for confirming permission, but it simply denies it. Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: Make sure that you have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the manifest.

Comment: I have to ask did you add it to the manifest file?

Comment: Yes, it is requested in the manifest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have discovered the solution, however the cause of the problem is still a mystery to me. If anyone has an explination, it would be greatly appreciated. Basically my issue is a duplicate of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149210/storage-access-permission-is-not-visible-in-app-info). All I had to do is to change the following line from

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>
```

What does tools:node="replace" do?

Comment: Thank you. This worked. And for whoever going to face this next. You will need to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` as well, to your AndroidManifest file

Comment: why do we need to add `tools:node="replace"` and `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` ? what do they do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Runtime Permission Library by nabinbhandari
in you **build.gradle app module** file write this

```
 //Android Runtime Permission Library
        implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8'
```

In your Manifest file write

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and in Activity declare these variables

```
    String[] permissions = new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    String rationale = "Please provide storage permission to proceed ...";
```

And in your onCreate() Method write this

```
Permissions.Options options = new Permissions.Options()
                .setRationaleDialogTitle("Info")
                .setSettingsDialogTitle("Warning");

        Permissions.check(MainActivity.this, permissions, rationale, options, new PermissionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onGranted() {
                // do your task.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permissions granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDenied(Context context, ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
                // permission denied
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permissions denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: I used this code. It tells me that the required permissions have not been set and then it directs me into settings where it does not let me set storage permissions. The only permission I can set there is Location permission. It feels like I'm doing something wrong with manifest. And if I want to manually set the permission, I cannot find my app on the list of storage permissions.

Comment: can you show me your manifest file? Use paste bin website and share link here.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle requested permission using this method (works with android 10), [Here is the documentation.](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case PERMISSION_REQUEST_ID_STORAGE:
                    // permisstion granted by user
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case PERMISSION_REQUEST_ID_STORAGE:
                    // permission denied by user
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```