# WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission error without using replace or legacy attribute

Tags: android, manifest, android-download-manager, android-storage

I used WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

And at first time, I wrote

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

But permission wasn't granted. And I looked for the solution and I finally got,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>
```

It worked. But I also found that I need to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

So, what I am using now is this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"/>
```

However, I don't know what the attributes do. what do node and android:requestLegacyExternalStorage do?
["Required permission was denied!" when requesting WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140976/required-permission-was-denied-when-requesting-write-external-storage)

Comment: On devices with Android M or above, permissions need to be granted by the user on runtime, check for runtime permissions on google.

Comment: @DarShan yes, but when you don't use the attributes, Runtime permission result is always denied.